# Remove all lines in single file NOT matching keywords aligned in first column

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort, emacs, printf

I need to extract a series of lines identified by a keyword in the first column and print them in the same linear order.

The file is divided into sections delimited by a line of hyphens or equal signs and contain a keyword line (possibly followed by a paragraph), there are several keywords, but I only need to extract these:

```
Date:
Name:
Contact:
RefID:
Status:
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: [edit] your question to show an example of the input file and the expected output

Comment: Kindly post an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `grep -e "^Name.*" -e "^Date.*"` and so on